# Web Configuration, Security in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, database-security, oracle-application-server

I want to build an web application in Oracle APEX, where i want users to enter into the database server through the application server, thus i can ensure more security in my application. IF this is hard, then is there any other way where i can ensure more security in a web application in Oracle APEX?

Comment: I think you need to review installation options, because this is what Tomcat, HTTP Server, WLS do. APEX is very secure, leveraging off db security. http://joelkallman.blogspot.com.au/2016/01/is-oracle-application-express-secure.html

Comment: Whether only the database server will provide more security? or a database server with a application server will provide more security? Please help.

Comment: Please clarify what you think you mean. You can't run Apex without an application server. The security of your setup will depend on how well you secure access to both the database and your application server.

Comment: Thank You. -Jeffrey Kemp

Answer (score 0):

Oracle APEX is a very stable and secure environement.

As is,

- you can encrypt and enforce high level passwords for the users
- you can lock account to avoid brute force attacks
- Devs and admins have accounts locked after a few attempts by default to avoid this issue
- The service can be easily configured with any SSL
- Webservices, like most of them, can be programmed to use access_tokens and other validations.

To my knowledge any additions security could be configured on the server and firewall. So I would say that you can do I lot, but it is up to you to perform good practices when defining your system's security.

Hope ity helps and good luck! :)